# Revoke web browser access from PS4 using router

Tags: networking, router, security, home-networking, parental-controls

Is it possible to configure a router to revoke HTTP access (I think that's what it would be called?) from a device on the network? In this case, a PS4.

But I'd still like it to be possible to play games online.

I tried setting up the parental controls on the console itself but they don't seem great for a number of reasons.

Annoyingly it doesn't seem possible to uninstall the browser from the console, so I'd rather just try and block access to browsing websites using the router instead if possible.

Comment: Yes, most routers have this capability. They also can blacklist certain websites, and block all internet traffic to/from. Or make a "whitelist" of only allowed websites.

Answer (score 1):

It would be possible but unlikely to be practical, as many services used by games and by the console's own firmware are also built on top of the same HTTP(S).

Comment: Thanks, I googled it but read some different opinions about whether games use HTTP(S)... do you know what sort of settings I'd need to change on the router? I'm tempted to give it a go and see if it works how I need it